# in react redux state is not updating while loading user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Problem Description:
I am encountering an issue where the `login` value in my Redux store is updating for login logout register part but loadingUser its not getting updated.Even though the in LoadUser function is dispatching
LoadUserSuccess but login value is not updating.
I've provided my code below and would like to understand why this issue is happening.

// App.js

```
import './App.css';    
import Login from './component/LoginRegis/login';
import Navbar from './component/Navbar/navbar';
import Footer from './component/Footer/footer';
import Book from './component/Book/book';
import { useEffect} from 'react';
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { LoadUser} from "./Action/user"

function App() { 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isLogged = useSelector((state) => state.user.login);
  console.log(isLogged);

  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(LoadUser())
    },[dispatch])

  return (
    <div className="app">
    {isLogged && < Navbar/>}
    {isLogged && < Book />}
    {!isLogged && < Login/>}
    {isLogged &&< Footer/>}
     </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

//Redux action file

```
import axios from "axios";

export const LoginUser = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {

    dispatch({    
      type: "LoginRequest"
    })

    const data = await axios.post("api/v1/login/", {email, password}, {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      }
    });

    dispatch({
      type: "LoginSuccess",
      payload: data.user
    })

  } catch (error) {

    dispatch({
      type: "LoginFailure",
      payload: error
    })

  }    
};

export const RegisterUser = (userDetails) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {

    dispatch({
     type: "RegisterRequest"
    })

    const data = await axios.post("api/v1/register/", {userDetails}, {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      }
    });

    dispatch({
      type: "RegisterSuccess",
      payload: data.user
    })

  } catch (error) {

    dispatch({
      type: "RegisterFailure",
      payload: error
    })

  }
};

export const LoadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {

    dispatch({
      type: "LoadUserRequest",
    });

    const { data } = await axios.get("api/v1/me/");

    dispatch({
      type: "LoadUserSuccess",
      payload: data.user,
    });

  } catch (error) {

    dispatch({
      type: "LoadUserFailure",
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });

  }
};

export const LogoutUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "LogoutUserRequest",
    });

    await axios.get("api/v1/logout/");

    dispatch({
      type: "LogoutUserSuccess"
    });

  } catch (error) {

    dispatch({
      type: "LogoutUserFailure",
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });

  }   
};
```

//Reducer userjs

```
import { createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState={login :false}
export const userReducer =  createReducer(initialState,{
    RegisterRequest:(state)=>{
        state.loading = true
    },
    RegisterSuccess:(state, action)=>{
        state.loading = false
        state.user = action.payload
    },    
    RegisterFailure:(state, action)=>{
        state.loading = false
        state.error = action.payload
    },
    LoginRequest:(state)=>{
        state.loading = true
        state.login = false
    },
    LoginSuccess:(state, action)=>{
        state.loading = false
        state.login = true
        state.user = action.payload
    },
    LoginFailure:(state, action)=>{
        state.loading = false;
        state.login = false;
        state.error = action.payload
    },
    LoadRequest:(state)=>{
        state.loading = true
    },
    LoadSuccess:(state, action)=>{
        state.loading = false;
        state.login= true;
        state.user = action.payload
    },
    LoadFailure:(state, action)=>{
        state.loading = false
        state.login= false;
        state.error = action.payload 
    }, 
    LogoutUserRequest: (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      },
    LogoutUserSuccess: (state) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.login = false;
        state.user = null;
      },
    LogoutUserFailure: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.login = true;
        state.error = action.payload;
      },
    clearErrors: (state) => {
        state.error = null;
      }
})
```

//store.js

```
import {configureStore}from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { userReducer } from "./Reducer/User"
const store =configureStore({
    reducer:{ user : userReducer}
})
export default store;
```

i try to update in this manner

```
  state = {
           ...state,
           loading = false,
           login = true, 
           user = action.payload
          }
```

but stiil it didn't work

Comment: Make sure your code is properly formatted, so that people here can understand the problem and help you.

Comment: You are dispatching `LoadUserRequest`,  `LoadUserSuccess`, and `LoadUserFailure` but in your reducer you have `LoadRequest`,  `LoadSuccess`, and `LoadFailure`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are manually dispatching actions that have no reducer cases for them. `LoadUser` action is dispatching `LoadUserRequest`, `LoadUserSuccess`, and `LoadUserFailure` actions, but the reducers handle `LoadRequest`, `LoadSuccess`, and `LoadFailure` actions.

Update the actions that `LoadUser` is dispatching to match the reducer cases.

```js
export const LoadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: "LoadRequest" });

    const { data } = await axios.get("api/v1/me/");

    dispatch({
      type: "LoadSuccess",
      payload: data.user,
    });
  } catch (error) {

    dispatch({
      type: "LoadFailure",
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
```

This appears to be an exercise in "How to use Redux-Toolkit" without actually using Redux-Toolkit (RTK). You are hand-writing the actions/reducers the old way. I would suggest rewriting your code to take advantage of RTK and much of its code generation.

Example:

```js
import {
  createSlice,
  createAsyncThunk,
  isFulfilled,
  isPending,
  isRejectedWithValue,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
```

```js
// Called as `dispatch(loginUser({ email, password }));
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/loginUser",
  async ({ email, password }, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.post(
        "api/v1/login/",
        { email, password },
        {
          headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          }
        }
      );

      return data.user;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/registerUser",
  async (userDetails, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.post(
        "api/v1/register/",
        { userDetails },
        {
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
          }
        }
      );

      return data.user;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);

export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/loadUser",
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("api/v1/me/");

      return data.user;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);

export const logoutUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/logoutUser",
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      await axios.get("api/v1/logout/");
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

```js
const initialState = {
  login: false
};

export const userReducer = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    clearErrors: (state) => {
      state.error = null;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(logoutUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = null;
        state.login = false;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.login = true;
      })
      .addMatcher(
        isPending(loginUser, registerUser, loadUser, logoutUser),
        (state) => {
          state.loading = true;
        }
      )
      .addMatcher(
        isFulfilled(loginUser, registerUser, loadUser, logoutUser),
        (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.error = null;
        }
      )
      .addMatcher(
        isFulfilled(loginUser, registerUser, loadUser),
        (state, action) => {
          state.user = action.payload;
        }
      )
      .addMatcher(
        isRejectedWithValue(loginUser, registerUser, loadUser, logoutUser),
        (state) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.error = action.payload;
        }
      );
  },
})
```

Note: I may have missed some of the state mapping from your old reducers to the new reducers, but this should be sufficient enough an example to understand how to work with Redux-Toolkit and current Redux patterns.